# Redirecting an output of a python script to a page on Wordpress

Tags: python, wordpress, cgi

I have a python script that works correctly and is called by a page in my Wordpress website. This script generates a table that I wish to be generated inside a Wordpress page and not in an outside HTML page.

Tha page that calls the script is this (it's in Portuguese, but it generates the Moon Phases to an year. Just enter some yer in the box "Ano" and click the "Gerar Fases da Lua" button):

http://astronomia.blog.br/efemerides/fases-da-lua/

The output for 2013 is like this:

http://astronomia.blog.br/cgi-bin/efemerides/fssl.py?mform_ano=2013&mform_epoca=2000&mform_fuso=EBST

So, I want to redirect this output to a page inside the site, not an outside page like that. Anyone can help?

Comment: In short, you need to call run the python script from the php script that renders the page (using [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or something like that). The python script output would be the result of `shell_exec`, so all oyu'll have to do is to `echo` it. Or post-process if the format does not suit your need. Or wrap into anything. It's just a string.

Comment: As @J0HN suggests this requires calling the Python interpreter from PHP. If you are using Apache mod_python then there maybe some tricks other than that this question is going to open a huge can of worms. It would be possible with running Python application as a WSGI app in a WSGI server and gathering the output as you would a HTTP page.

Comment: Thank you very much @JOHN and JOE, I'm gonna try it out!

Comment: Thank you very much JOHN and @JOE, I'm gonna try it out!

Comment: I'm calling the script like that <form action="/en/cgi-bin/efemerides/fssl.py" method="get">, I will change to use the shell_exec

Comment: I found that you can use iframes to embed something into wordpress: [iframe src="http://astronomia.blog.br/efemerides/fases-da-lua/" width="100%" height="480"]

Comment: Thank you, @User. My script generates the output you can see in the simplest way, with many "prints" designing a HTML page. I nee to put this output inside a page of the websit to keep the look of the site. I tought it would be possible to redirect the output to a page in the wordpress, but it seems that it is not possible. I'm trying to call the script from a PHP page, and handling the parameters that are passed. As soon as I get it I'll post here the final solution.

Comment: If I were you I would consider iframe as a last resort. In my professional experience, iframes caused much more troubles than helped. In order to not to be bare-worded, iframes adds a magnitude of complexity on javascript interactions, sometimes cause weird issues with ajax and are served in a distinct request. So if you are serving someting in an iframe and have all the css/js needed for main window in iframe as well you just load them twice, essentially loading the same resources twice. So, if you can avoid them - avoid them :)

Comment: Thank you all. The final solution me and a friend found was:
1)create a customized template in WP;
2)create a page using this template;
3)in the HTML form call this page with method POST: <form action="http://page/" method="POST">
4)in the customized template, recover the parameters passed by the HTML form with /$var1 = $_POST["par1"];$var2 = $_POST['par2'], etc.
5)in the same customized template call the script using the parameters like echo shell_exec ($path_script.' '.$var1.' '.$var2.')

So, the output of the python script goes into this page, created with the customized template.